# Google crawl errors "DNS issue- link unreachable and time out errors

Tags: google, google-search-console

Can any one tell me why Googlebot cant fetch my website and its links? I have a website and for past 30 days Google Webmasters can't fetch any links from my website. This caused the removal of my website from Google search. I also tried "fetch as Googlebot" option but it failed. The error it's showing is "**DNS issue**-Links **unreachable** and **Time out** error". I also have Google Analytics and Bing Webmasters Tools accounts which work fine (Bing crawls and fetches links from my website). I can access my website through browsers also. I have searched other forums and found out that it may be my hosting providers blocking Googlebot. When I wrote to them they told me that they have allowed Googlebot to my website.

Now I have become a little frustrated about this problem. I really don't know why this error is occurring. I cant even add Google AdSense because of this problem. If anyone has or had this kind of error can they suggest what causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from a Google Employee about the same problem http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/webmasters/0t6FGoQV7wc/1x40gX6GU8QJ

> It looks like most requests we send to both of your DNS servers are
>   timing out since ca. beginning February. In general, this can mean
>   that we won't be able to crawl your content or read your Sitemap
>   files. I would recommend working together with your hoster to try to
>   find out more -- or if you can't, perhaps move your DNS to a different
>   server temporarily so that you can work out the issues without having
>   to worry about your site.

I would contact your hosting provider, and DNS provider to ask what the problem is.

Here are common webmaster tool errors 
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35147